# Change the default polymorphic type-column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, polymorphism

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to change the default type-column name used by a polymorphic association.

For example, if I have this class:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

and I implement for that a polymorphic association, *I would like to use the type-column names `comm_id` and `comm_type` instead of `commentable_id` and `commentable_type`*. **Is it possible? If so, what I have to change for the Comment class?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way in Rails API to override the default column name used for polymorphic associations.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980320/rails-polymorphic-association-legacy-database/1984124#1984124) for a possible solution.

Comment: I have to note that the way exists since Rails 4.2.1 release, and you can found it by a link posted here. But it is not the first answer(which is marked as correct). So better to click this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41179078/1514072). Have a good day;)

Answer (score 4):

I did this in rails 6 on my legacy database using the `foreign_type:` option. This should work for rails >= 4.2.1 ([see here](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to))

```
# booking model
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_notes, as: :notable, foreign_type: :note_type, foreign_key: :type_id
end
# booking model
# here polymorphic columns are `note_type` and `type_id`
class UserNote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :notable, polymorphic: true, foreign_type: :note_type, foreign_key: :type_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, why not just change the association to:

```
# Comment
belongs_to :comm, :polymorphic => true

# Everything else
has_many :comments, :as => :comm
```